# Mcrypt is required on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: config, server

I am using Craft on Ubuntu 12.04 servers without problems, but when trying to run it on Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) I always get the message

> Mcrypt is required.

I installed it, however, via...

```
apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql-server php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-gd php5-mcrypt php5-mysql
```

...and restarted the web server afterwards. Any hints? Maybe this is a bug with the way craft checks for mcrypt?

Answer (score 8):

I had to run `sudo php5enmod mcrypt` to enable the module.

It seems this has changed between 12.04 and 14.04—in 12.04 it was enabled automatically.

Comment: just a FYI, this command is required on ubuntu 14.04 ubuntu lamp prebuilt VM on digital ocean.